# How to return string[]?

Tags: javascript, typescript

my question is - how return a string[]. Right now TS throw error because every element of array is type of ( T[keyof T] extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T[keyof T] )
How do i accept 'property' argument  as a string for return string[]. If i just write string instead keyof T, TS throw error because  on the line item[property] TS can't see propert in unknown type.

```
interface IMovie {
  genre: string[];
  actors: string[];
}

const movies: IMovie[] = [
  {
    genre: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi', 'Adventure'],
    actors: ['Scarlett Johansson', 'Florence Pugh', 'David Harbour'],
  }
];

function collectByProperty<T>(arr: T[], property: keyof T): string[] {
  const array = arr.map((item) => item[property]).flat();
  const elem = array[0];
  const final = [...new Set(array)];
  return final;
}
const genres = collectByProperty<IMovie>(movies, 'genre');
const actors = collectByProperty<IMovie>(movies, 'actors');

console.log(genres);
console.log(actors);
```

Tried to create variable in function body and write in it property.

Comment: try typecasting into the said property if you know that is going to be returned

Comment: if you mean operator 'as', TS don't throw error and array have type string[] but console show that array which can have any types and no errors.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map` then `flat`:

```
const array = arr.flatMap((item) => item[property]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **flatten** the array in your collectByProperty function because it initially produces an array of arrays (like `[['Action', 'Sci-Fi'], ['Drama']]`). Flattening this converts it into a single-level array (`['Action', 'Sci-Fi', 'Drama']`), matching the expected output.